# Is SEO is the only major benefit for CSR + SSR web applications? (nuxtjs, nextjs)

Tags: next.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

So basically the only major benefit implementing SSR + CSR is SEO? Because if you think about it SSR actually is slow in initial load time because you have to wait for the server to render and respond with the HTML + JS which needs a nodejs server with all the complicated configurations for production while in

CSR you receive instantly the bare bones HTML and JS (can be cached) which can just be hosted on a file bucket with no complicated server configuration, also now a days browsers / computers / phones are actually fast enough to render components quickly so initial load time is not an issue. And also you can actually do lazy loading for components.

So aside from SEO, you actually add more cons when implementing  SSR + CSR.

Anyone please do correct me if Im wrong

SSR + CSR vs CSR. Cons seems to outweighs using SSR+CSR than just CST

Comment: SSR + CSR is faster than just CSR. You should checkout [First contentful paint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First_contentful_paint). Using SSR, you are offloading the API requests from client side to server side. Also, you can cache a lot of things at backend. You can also cache all the static assets in a SSR application. You have to just find the right balance between what should be server-rendered on every request and what should be cached. I am not doing justice to SSR because I haven't covered all the points, but to summarize, SEO is not the only benefit.

Comment: @vighnesh153 you could post that as an answer.

Comment: @vighnesh153 SSR is not faster than CSR, and it might be slower because server renders for all users. When there will be a pick where more users enter page at same time, server might slower sends requests. And the page needs to be rendered either on server side or client side.

Comment: Read about crawling a website. You need SSR so other programmers can crawl your app. Like kissu wrote if you make a blog app, you want to share your posts if you have just SPA with CSR no one can share a nice Card of your web page on Facebook LinkedIn etc. because all they get is plain starter HTML theme with not rendered components from your page.

Comment: @Mises the crawling part is mainly SEO which OP refers to. SSR can be done on a unique Node server but also in an Edge Rendered environment where you have no notion of "load" because each instance is unique.

Comment: @kissu I'm not sure what you want to say. I don't know what Edge Rendered is. I just want to point that SEO (Search Engine Optimization) friendly websites are easy to crawl for other programmers creating web apps. SEO not means only search engines will benefit from it.

Comment: @Mises Puppeteer is totally able to scrap an SPA. Doesn't bring more value to anybody else than search engines. And friendly social cards are still part of search engines IMO. Especially since they are using OG tags anyway (not even sure that those require SSR). As for the Edge Rendering, that one will be able to SSR your app without getting slower the more visitors you have on your website.

Comment: @kissu You speak about future. I know that there is a possibility to make an API where you use puppeteer and chromium to get meta tags from SPA pages. The thing is, companies are not evolving enough fast. If you don't make SSR app, users won't be able to paste their nice cards on Facebook because Facebook is using old solutions. I know, and I'm glad that search engines are using Puppeteer solutions like Google.

Comment: @kissu It is like with OOP and functional programming. First, one should never be so popular then second one.

Comment: @kissu Best solution for web would be to add extra functionality to browser engines so when you fetch some link, and you get HTML file it will check are it is SPA and renders it and give you rendered HTML file. If the app is not a web app, it could make a request to a browser to get a rendered HTML file. Same like with authentication with provider. There won't be a need for API with puppeteer solutions.

Answer (score 3):

SSR can be helpful because it will display the static content ahead of time, providing the user with a visual rather than waiting for a spinner to create the whole thing.

You will have a hydration phase, but you can skip parts of those or even not use them at all (Islands Architecture like AstroJS does or with some other packages).

SSR will also bring the SEO part as you know, which is quite important for some types of apps (blogs, marketplaces, StackOverflow etc...).

The SSR step can be rather quick, especially if using Edge Side Rendering. You can also cache it and the configuration doesn't need to be difficult (it can help with memory leaks too because you will kill it everytime), the "charge" supported by a server is not a consideration anymore

It can consume fewer resources regarding the end-user devices because no: not everybody is using the latest iPhone 14 Pro. The most common device is still a Motorola G5 or alike (in terms of raw power). Not to say that people can come from various countries where bandwidth/expensive phones are not a thing yet.

Database delays are also not a thing if they are done ahead of time and can be skipped by the client.

Again, more and more advanced configurations are feasible but it all comes down to how much you want to optimize your app and how much money you make out of it.
Nowadays, tools like Qwik, Marko, and Astro are popular because they are joining the group of cool kids shipping less JS to your visitors. It is always nice when you see how much money your business can generate with some fine-tuned performance metrics.

If you have a chill casual chat app, keep it as a SPA.
Also, not all apps need SSR/SSG. Some of them can stick to SPA (dashboard, gmail-like etc...).

One is not better than another, they all have their pro/cons. The thing is that you need to understand how to efficiently use each one of them in the best situation. And Vue/React don't do all those things in the same way too...

---

You can give a read to those great authors, they are quite good at explaining the performance considerations and future great frameworks (aside from the usual React/Next etc..):

- https://dev.to/tigt
- https://dev.to/ryansolid
- https://dev.to/filrakowski
- https://twitter.com/mhevery
- https://twitter.com/danielcroe

Comment: But what if this static content relies on an API call, that would mean the rendering in backend would wait for the API call to be done. Unlike the SPA they will see first at least a loading animation while its doing the API call compare to SSR+CSR that the browser will show nothing because its waiting for the SSR+CSR to finish rendering with the API call. 

So wouldn't that make SPA better than SSR + CSR in this situation if SEO is not needed right? And if yes does it mean SSR + CSR is only needed if SEO is a priority?

Comment: @ReneRowelldelaRama there are various parameters on how to properly serialize on the backend and frontend (like Marko does) but usually, doing things on the backend will always be faster than on the frontend. The backend can also be quite powerful regarding some DBs, cache etc. Creating a DOM in CSR is expensive. The question is more about the type of the app: if it's protected behind a login, there is no point. Backend will still be faster but that would be useless. It's more of a gray area than black or white only as you can see. And no, SSR is not only for SEO as mentioned above.

Comment: thank you so much! You really are a God's sent :-)